# Devido ao NAT a contagem de acessos por IP é imperfeita?

Tags: aplicação-web, redes

Achei difícil encontrar conteúdo na internet sobre isso. Gostaria de saber no geral o que é NAT (Network Address Translation), como ele mapeia os IPs privados em um IP público e principalmente onde isso é usado atualmente.

Quando contrato um plano de internet em casa se duas pessoas acessarem uma aplicação na internet ao mesmo tempo desta rede, o IP do remetente presente nos pacotes que chegam ao servidor dessa aplicação será o mesmo? Isso significa que elas estão por trás de um NAT?

Alguma aplicações web utilizam o endereço de IP para certas finalidades, como por exemplo contar quantas vezes um link foi acessado. Se eu implementar uma aplicação que conte todos os cliques no link, uma mesma pessoa pode clicar várias vezes no link e isso será contado.

Mas contar o número de IPs que acessaram o link também não é perfeito. Queria entender melhor o NAT para saber em que situações utilizar o IP do remetente pode ser útil.

Comment: O artigo em português é meio fraquinho, mas é um bom começo https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation - Como usual, a versão em inglês é mais completa https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation - Um pouco da dificuldade de conteúdo nacional é graças aos alguns "coronéis" da Wikipedia, que a pretexto de ajudarem a organizar o site, fazem questão de atrapalhar os editores nacionais querendo por a mão em todos os artigos mesmo sem entenderem do assunto (entretanto, tradução voluntária eles aceitam sem questionar tanto, mesmo que o original contenha baboseiras).

Comment: Acho que aí está tendo a confusão entre o provedor e a rede da sua casa. Se você faz NAT na sua casa ou não, depende de você (por exemplo, para ter vários pcs na mesma rede). O provedor normalmente te dá um IP real (mas já vi casos em que dão um IP baseado em NAT, em situações meio precárias).

Comment: Só depende de você. Quando eu usava o Virtua, da Net, num PC só, usava o IP real. Depois passei a usar NAT para ter mais PCs na rede. Meus clientes normalmente usam o IP verdadeiro no servidor, e NAT para o resto da rede (eu deixo normalmente o servidor fazer o NAT, quando é caso de um servidor só em empresa pequena, e o servidor atende coisa externa).

Comment: Mesmo em ADSL, se você vai usar NAT ou não depende basicamente de como configura o roteador ou o PC. Por exemplo, se seu PC fizer a conexão PPPOE, que é comum nesses casos, ele vai pegar o IP externo usualmente. O mais importante é entender que o NAT é uma técnica para fazer maquinas diferentes usarem um mesmo IP, nem mais nem menos. Se esse IP vai ser válido na internet ou não, se vai ser usado em redes internas, se vai ter um NAT depois de outro ou não, são questões não relacionadas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A melhor forma de entender o `NAT` é pensar que todo pacote `TCP/UDP` vindo de uma rede ou determinado IP poderá ser alterado na saída pelo seu roteador/gateway(desde que este tenha função de efetuar NAT), quando uma regra NAT é aplicada o cabeçalho deste pacote que define o IP de origem é alterado para um novo IP(público ou não).

O processo de mudança ocorre quando o pacote sai do equipamento de origem com o IP de sua rede interna e chega até o gateway da sua rede interna que estará efetuando um NAT, portando quando o pacote chega no gateway o NAT efetua a troca do IP dentro do cabeçalho do pacote e envia a requisição para frente, esse processo permite comunicações com outras redes que não possuam rotas para sua rede privada, o destino não vai conhecer qual IP de dentro da sua rede privada fez essa comunicação, pois todas as requisições foram traduzidas para um IP específico!

> onde isso é usado atualmente?

Simplesmente em todos os lugares, esse processo permite que redes internas inteiras possam acessar a internet, quando se tem uma rede interna com IP's privados a única saída para que todos estes IP's consigam navegar para a internet é efetuar um `NAT` de toda sua classe ou dos IPs desejados para o IP público do seu link contratado, este é um exemplo que talvez seja simples de visualizar, mas é claro o `NAT` também pode ser utilizado para efetuar a tradução internamente dentro de sua rede onde talvez você precise utilizar destas artimanhas para algo pontual e específicas.

> Quando contrato um plano de internet em casa se duas pessoas acessarem
>   uma aplicação na internet ao mesmo tempo, seu IP público visto do
>   servidor será o mesmo? Isso é um NAT?

A maioria das suas dúvidas foram respondidas na resposta anterior eu acredito, ficou confuso a parte do "Servidor", mas é o que eu disse, para o resto do mundo não importa quantos IP's diferentes da sua rede interna faça acesso, todo o mundo só irá conhecer o IP público, ou seja todos os acessos de sua rede interna são traduzidos para o IP público.

Contar acessos somente olhando IP's nunca será a melhor maneira, em geral é feita uma análise dos logs no servidor que está recebendo o acesso, nestes logs além de conter o IP de origem (Nateado ou não, sua aplicação nunca vai saber), também terá informações do SO utilizado, versão do Browser, e presume-se que se um mesmo IP fez acesso com browsers e SO diferentes, então possivelmente será de pessoas diferentes. Não existe meio 100% seguro de calcular informações de acesso, na maioria das vezes é uma estimativa. Agora se você desenvolver os clients que vão fazer acesso a sua aplicação, então é possível partir do mesmo princípio de análise de logs, você pode então gerar ID's únicos para cada cliente e que de alguma maneira você tenha essa informação arquivada via log em seu servidor, desta maneira toda requisição independente de IP com Nat ou não terá um registro único em seus logs do servidor.

Comment: A resposta foi muito boa! Mas parece que o pessoal achou que a pergunta não está no escopo do site. Então mudei pra tentar relacionar um pouco mais com programação! Se você puder editar a resposta para a pergunta modificada, ai eu aceito ela :)